# docker daemon doesn't run on vagrant vm(centos/ubuntu)

Tags: docker, vagrant

While trying to run docker daemon (docker -d) it just gets stuck, I have tried this on a vagrant box with centos and ubuntu.

```
 docker -d
INFO[0000] +job serveapi(unix:///var/run/docker.sock)   
INFO[0000] Listening for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock) 
WARN[0000] WARNING: Udev sync is not supported. This will lead to unexpected behavior, data loss and errors 
INFO[0000] +job init_networkdriver() 
INFO[0000] -job init_networkdriver() = OK (0)           
INFO[0000] WARNING: mountpoint for memory not found

INFO[0000] Loading containers: start.                   

INFO[0000] Loading containers: done.                    
INFO[0000] docker daemon: 1.5.0 a8a31ef; execdriver: native-0.2; graphdriver: devicemapper 
INFO[0000] +job acceptconnections()                     
INFO[0000] -job acceptconnections() = OK (0)
```

Any suggestions on what the problem is ?

Comment: did you notice the message `WARNING: Udev sync is not supported. This will lead to unexpected behavior, data loss and errors` ? Something is definitely wrong, try stopping and restarting the daemon in debug mode with `docker -D -d`

Comment: I don't see any errors here (just warnings), and no indication that the docker daemon is not working.  What sort of problems have you encountered?

Answer (score 0):

Does `sudo docker info` show that you are using the devicemapper storage driver?
There is a bug with devicemapper on Ubuntu right now: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/10705

Try working around by installing aufs and restarting docker. Docker will use aufs by default if available.
https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/#dependencies_1

Here's my output showing aufs:

> ```
> vagrant@controller:~$ sudo docker info
> Containers: 0
> Images: 23
> Storage Driver: aufs
>  Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
>  Backing Filesystem: extfs
>  Dirs: 24
> Execution Driver: native-0.2
> Kernel Version: 3.13.0-46-generic
> Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
> CPUs: 4
> Total Memory: 3.86 GiB
> Name: controller
> ID: MBSR:QUKL:5TJK:B74D:IV6N:XQMM:FLRE:WWRC:RIMG:NDX6:M6ES:XKLJ
> WARNING: No swap limit support
> ```